# Crystalline Sliver and targets

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Text on card says:

> Slivers cannot be the target of spells or abilities.

Does it mean that other slivers cannot affect each other, while Crystalline Sliver is in play.

For example, Fury Sliver won't give double strike to all slivers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Oracle text of [Crystalline Sliver](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Crystalline%20Sliver) now says:

> All Slivers have shroud. (They can't be the targets of spells or abilities.)

It applies to all Slivers, not **all other slivers**. (Which, [would be worded](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=+%5B%22All%20other%22%5D%7C%7Ctext=+%5B%22All%20other%22%5D) that way if that is what they meant.) It means precisely what the reminder text (or the cards old text) says, Sliver creatures **cannot be targeted** by spells or abilities that have **target** in the rules text. [Fury Sliver](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Fury%20Sliver) still gives Slivers **double strike**, [Muscle Sliver](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Muscle%20Sliver) still grants Slivers a +1/+1 Power/Toughness bonus.

What it does prevent is Spells like [Assassinate](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Assassinate) from targeting a tapped Sliver, or Slivers with [activated or triggered abilities](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=+%5B%22Target%20sliver%22%5D%7C%7Ctext=+%5B%22Target%20sliver%22%5D) (or any other Activated or Triggered Abilities) from targeting Slivers with their abilities.